# Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then so is $f \times g$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $g: B \rightarrow D$. Defined $f \times g: A \times B \rightarrow C \times D$ to be $(f \times g)(a,b) = (f(a),g(b))$. Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then so is $f \times g$.

This is what I need to prove. I have a proof here, but I'm not sure how to interpret the definition of injectivity with the product of two functions. Does it make sense to say that $(f(a), g(c)) \neq (f(b), g(d)) \Rightarrow (a,c) \neq (b,d)$? or should I approach this proof separately such as $(f(a), g(c)) \Rightarrow a \neq c$?

Here's my proof:

Assume $f$ and $g$ are both injective. we need to prove for any $x,y \in A$ and $x,y \in B$ such that $x \neq y$. Since $f$ and $g$ are injective, we have $f(x) \neq f(y) \Rightarrow x \neq y$ and $g(x) \neq g(y) \Rightarrow x \neq y$. Let us take $(f \times g)(a,c)$ and $(f \times g)(b,d)$. Then, we have $(f \times g)(a,c) = (f(a),g(c)) = (a, c)$ and $(f \times g)(b,d) = (f(b), g(d)) = (b, d)$. By the definition of injectivity, we have $(f(a),g(c)) \neq (f(b),g(d)) \Rightarrow (a,c) \neq (b,d)$. Thus, $f \times g$ is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a step back, injectivity of a mapping $\phi$ means that
$$
(\phi(x_1) = \phi(x_2)) \mbox{ implies } x_1 = x_2. \quad (*)
$$
So, yes, if $x_1 = (a_1, b_1)$ and $x_2 = (a_2, b_2)$, and if we define
$$
\phi( (a, b) ) = (f(a), g(b)),
$$
then--as you correctly think--we interpret the equalities in $(*)$ as equalities of ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Any function $f$ on some domain $D$ called injective iff

$f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ for all $x,y\in D$.

Now, back to your problem:

$(f\times g)(a,b)=(f\times g)(c,d)\implies (f(a),g(b))=(f(c),g(d))\implies f(a)=f(c),$ and $g(b)=g(d)$. Now, by injectivity of $f$ and $g$,
$a=c, b=d$. Consequently, $(a,b)=(c,d)$.